# How to upload a file using jquery confirm, iframe and backbone?

Tags: iframe, backbone.js, confirm

I try to upload a file using a jquery confirm box with backbone. I use iframe transport. Calling the web service gives an error "**The current request is not a multipart request**". What I am doing wrong?

```
$.confirm({
            'title'     : "Upload a file",
            'message'   : "<form id='uploadForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"+"<input type='file' id='uploadFile' />"+"</form>",
            'buttons'   : {
                'Yes'   : {
                    'name' : "Upload",
                    'class' : 'blue',
                    'action': function(event){ 
                        //TODO Call webservice

                        $.ajax({
                                iframe: true,
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/api/data/upload",
                                files: $(":file", this),


                            }).complete(function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
                        //});
                    }
                },
                'No'    : {
                    'name' : "Cancel",
                    'class' : 'gray',
                    'action': function(){}  
                }
            }
        });
```